Does Webpack remove by default consol.log() in an Angular Application or has to be set with a proper configuration or plugin?
This is my first post, hope I'll be clear with the question and the context that led me to ask it. I am a novice\amateur "web programmer" ( just 1 and a half year of "working" background in Java and Javascript\Typescript with Angular ) and right now, with some friends, we are developing a small project to just get more into it in our free time.
We are far from a "complete project", but there were some discussion about vulnerability issues related to the log inside our .ts files. The basically understanding i have it's that webpack, in the bundling and packaging phase, create a main.js and polyfills.js file with the code minified and tranpiled.
Does Webpack remove by default consol.log() in an Angular Application ( in a production environment ) or has to be set with a proper configuration or plugin?
I know for sure that related to this topic ( vulnerabilty issues ), this is not the first thing that should bump in our mind and there are other issues that should be considered before this one. I also understand that maybe this post could trigger some real and professional programmer, and i aknowledge that.I have a lot of failures, practice and learnings ahead of me but i don't want to be afraid to ask.
P.S.: I tried to search for related topics but the only things i found was about optimization and extra data being transferred.
Thank you to everyone in advance just for the time spent.

Does this answer your question? Remove console.logs with Webpack & Uglify

webpack does not remove console.log alone, you would need a plugin or another tool

By default Webpack (or esbuild fwiw) won't remove console.log, some plugins might do it for you.
If your goal is to get debug code to be removed in prod builds, it might be interesting to guard theme behind a devMode flag and hace a DCE tools (Dead-code elimitation), like terser, remove it for you.

Yep, that was actually the goal! Thank you for your answer, I will read some docs and try to implement in my project. I'm really glad to have asked this question.
